# Sticky footer in Foundation 6

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, sticky-footer

I've been having some issues getting a sticky footer to work for a responsive page using the Foundation framework. It looks like the footer isn't recognizing the height of the article content. I've tried messing with the positioning, javascript solutions, and the common CSS solutions, but nothing seems to be working out. Any clues what might be going wrong? I'm guessing there's something super obvious I'm just looking over, but can't find it!

Here's the code: https://codepen.io/bublitzd/pen/grqPBp

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #D7DDE3;
    z-index: 0;
}

article {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 65vh;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-bottom: 5vh;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #000000;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by all the positioning you are doing. Just remove all the positioning and z-indexing and use the normal element order. For the top article you can set a negative top-margin to get the overlapping:

```
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #D7DDE3;
}

article {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: -10vh;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
}

footer { 
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured it was something along those lines, but my brain starting fizzing out. This works!